# MPI - why does the receive buffer of MPI_Reduce need to exist on every process?

Tags: c++, mpi

Imagine you have N mpi processes that each generates a large vector of floats. You want to sum these vectors in the mathematical sense (i.e. create a result vector whose i-th entry corresponds to the sum of the i-th entries in the N vectors.

You iterate through the vector and use MPI_Reduce in combination with MPI_SUM to generate the results vector on process 0. To save memory, you only create an empty results vector on process 0. It does not seem to work, the empty results vector needs to exist on any process. This seems to be extremely wasteful, so I imagine there is a workaround?

Here my code example:

'''

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;

int rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);


std::vector <double> myvec(3);
std::vector <double> myvec_sum;

// fill vector 
for(int i=0; i<myvec.size(); ++i){
    myvec[i] = i*rank;
}


if(rank == 0) myvec_sum.resize(3);      // only on rank 0 to save memory
    
for(int i=0; i<myvec_sum.size(); ++i){
        
    MPI_Reduce(&myvec[i], &myvec_sum[i], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, comm);      // will dead lock 
                                                                                // (code will only work if the "if(rank==0)" above is removed)
}


// print results
if(rank==0){
    std::cout<<"Results:"<<"\n";
    for(int i=0; i<myvec_sum.size(); ++i){
            std::cout << "i=" << i << " :  " << myvec_sum[i] << std::endl;
    }
}


MPI_Finalize();

return 0;

}
```

Edit:
Replacing

> ```
> if(rank == 0) myvec_sum.resize(3);        // only on rank 0 to save memory
>   
> for(int i=0; i<myvec_sum.size(); ++i){
>       
>   MPI_Reduce(&myvec[i], &myvec_sum[i], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, comm);
> ```
>
> }

with

> if(rank == 0) myvec_sum.resize(3);
> MPI_Reduce(&myvec[0], &myvec_sum[0], myvec.size(), MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, comm);

worked without problems. I still don't quite understand why my element-wise approach fails if not all the processes have the correct sized receive vector...

Comment: 1. You can get rid of that loop by a doing a reduction on muliple elements. Replace your `1` by `myvec.size()`. 2. The non-root processes can indeed have a null pointer for the receive buffer. This will never be accessed. You problem comes completely from the fact that you reduce every element separately.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, didn't know that I could reduce the vector all at once. But if you say that the non-root processes can have null pointers to the receive buff, why does it not work in my example then if I do it one by one?

Comment: please show your code with the null pointer.

Comment: I don't have one. I am asking why my code does not work.

Comment: the root cause is here: `for(int i=0; i<myvec_sum.size(); ++i)`